# SqlCeCommand insert C# do not really insert into database

Tags: c#, sql

when I try to insert, delete or update a record into .sdf database, the record is in the database temporary. When I run the application again the changes are not visible. I think that the commit function do not updates the database.

Here is my code for the insert function:

```
conn.Open();    
SqlCeTransaction transaction;
transaction = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);

SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

cmd.Transaction = transaction;

cmd.CommandText = 
"INSERT INTO tblCustomers " + " (LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, Street, City, Phone, TaxCountry, Dealer," + 
" Email, FEIN, DateOfBirth, SSAN, DriverLicense, State, Exp, Code, Notes)" + 
"VALUES (@last_name, @first_name, @middle_name, @street, @city, @phone_number, @tax_country, @dealer, @email," +
"@fein, @dateofbirth, @ssan, @driver_license, @stat, @exp, @code, @_note)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", textBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", textBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@middle_name", textBox10.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", textBox5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_number", textBox6.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tax_country", textBox7.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dealer", textBox17.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", textBox8.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fein", textBox18.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", Convert.ToDateTime(textBox12.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ssan", textBox11.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@driver_license", textBox13.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", textBox14.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@exp",Convert.ToDateTime(textBox15.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code", textBox16.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_note", textBox9.Text);

//cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

transaction.Commit(CommitMode.Deferred);

clearData();

conn.Close();
```

Do you have any idea to solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Is there any exception? What is the flush interval?

Comment: have you tried to change to `CommitMode.Immediate`

Comment: I used CommitMode.Immediate and it still doesn't work. Also I verified with database console.

Comment: are any exceptions being thrown on or before Commit is called?

Comment: no there is no exception thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should be modified:

```
transaction.Commit(CommitMode.Deferred);
```

You're using `CommitMode.Deferred` when you actually want `CommitMode.Immediate`.

See: [CommitMode Enumeration @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.commitmode.aspx)

If a deferred commit is what you really want, then you should check your connection string for the flush interval, and modify it to a shorter timespan. The default is 10 seconds.

See: [SqlCeConnectionString @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection.connectionstring.aspx)

Comment: I used CommitMode.Immediate but it still doesn't work. Also I verified into database console.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esdw1h9d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> Use Deferred mode for optimal performance; the changes will be flashed to disk within the timespan specified in the ConnectionString **FLUSH INTERVAL** property;

So it will take time. Otherwise you can use the `CommitMode.Immediate` to see effect immediately.

Comment: I used CommitMode.Immediate but it still doesn't work. The problem is the values which are inserted dynamically are stored temporarily. I insert a record, after 1 minute a want to verify if it was saved into database and it isn't saved. When I run again the application it appears into database. But when I close Visual Studio and reopen it, the record isn't into databse.